# Getting the latest row inserted to the sql for a certain ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a **Current Salary Report**

This is my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM payroll, employees
WHERE employees.username='$username'
AND payroll.id=employees.id";
```

And the output is:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o5XH.jpg) and by scrolling down, [this is the continuation of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruJ3c.jpg).

To sum it up, the query displays all the records of a certain ID but I would want it to display the last inserted data of this certain ID in the database. How can this happen?

Comment: Use order by id desc with limit what you want

Comment: Try `ORDER BY employees.id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: I am not sure I understand you well. Are you saying you get **all payroll records for each employee** and you just want **the last payroll record for each employee**? Do your payroll records have a time stamp or a sequence number?

Comment: Thanks! Order by and limit 1 works.

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest row you must order by `id desc` and to get only one record set `limit 1`.

So the code will be

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM payroll, employees
WHERE employees.username='$username'
AND payroll.id=employees.id ORDER BY employees.id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
```

Comment: Wow, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM payroll, employees
WHERE employees.username='$username'
AND payroll.id=employees.id ORDER BY employees.id DESC  LIMIT 1 "
```

if the newest ID is the largest value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this MySQL **ORDER BY** or **LIMIT**

```
$sql = "SELECT *
FROM payroll, employees
WHERE employees.username='$username'
AND payroll.id=employees.id ORDER BY employees.id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.*,t1.*
FROM payroll t1 join employees t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.username='$username' order by t2.id desc limit 1";
```